# Validate Year from the given date using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

How to validate year in the date using jquery?

For example if i have date like `"01/05/0001"` it should give a error.

Comment: How do you decide if the year is valid or not?

Comment: that is my question....is it possible or not?

Comment: Of course it's possible. See my answer below. I supposed that you need an year greater than `1900`.

Comment: Have a look http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2011/12/validate-date-using-jquery.html

Comment: Ya this is fine, but my problem is i don't know the exact range

Comment: @BabuReddy:- In that case your question doesnt make sense as then any year would be valid starting to 0 to 99999999.... The only thing which you can then check is that your year is integer or not(*Although then it would be vague*) or else you can check if the year is 4 digit ie., in YYYY pattern starting from 0001.

Comment: @Rahul:- Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @BabuReddy Note that using regular expressions for such a thing is slower than my solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that valid years are between `1500` and the current year which is here `2015`, so the validation will be like this:

**Code:**

```js
var str = "01/05/0001";
var year = str.match(/\/(\d{4})/)[1];
var currYear = new Date().toString().match(/(\d{4})/)[1];
if (year >= 1500 && year <= currYear) {
  alert(year + ' is valid.');
} else {
  alert(year + ' is an invalid year !');
}
```

**Explanation:**

We take the date and extract the year and compare it to a given previous year and the current one.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery. Use plain JS to manipulate the string and do a simple check. Let's suppose you consider the year valid if it's greater than `1900`:

```js
var str = "01/05/0001";
var year = str.split("/").pop();
if (!(year > 1900)) {
  alert("Invalid year: " + year);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to instead use datepicker and set the minimum date(*i.e, year range*) like this:

```
$("#textBox").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true, 
    changeYear: true, 
    yearRange: '1900:+0'
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery having the Date object you may use that to convert your string formatted date to Date in jquery and then fetch the year, month,day.

```
var date = new Date( "01/05/0001");
var year = date.getFullYear();
var month = date.getMonth();
var day = date.getDate();
if(year > 1950){
   //your valid condition code
}
else{
    // invalid condition code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using jquery validator.
this save me a lot of time.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkYear", function(value, element) {
    var year = $(element).val();
    return (year > 1950) && (year <= (new Date()).getFullYear());
}, "Invalid year");
```

to use:

```
field_year: {
   required: true,
   checkYear:true
}
```

hope this help.